# Create cron job for every five minutes?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to `Magento 1.9`. I have my own custom API which read last modified Product stock and do some updates. I need to make this API run every five minutes . Please help.

Comment: Would you like to use the built in magenta cron or the root crontab? You can do it in your cPanel.

Comment: I would like to build it programatically as a module. and please could you explain how can I use root crontab also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i mentioned module.

create Stackoverflow_Cronshedule.xml under app\etc\modules\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackoverflow_Cronshedule>
       <active>true</active>
       <codePool>local</codePool>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackoverflow_Cronshedule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

create etc.xml under app\code\local\Stackoverflow\Cronshedule\etc\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Stackoverflow_Cronshedule>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackoverflow_Cronshedule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <cronshedule>
        <class>Stackoverflow_Cronshedule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>cronshedule_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </cronshedule>
    </models>
  </global>    
    <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <cronshedule_lastmodifiedproduct>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>cronshedule/cron::lastModifiedProduct</model></run>
            </cronshedule_lastmodifiedproduct>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Create Cron.php file under app\code\local\Stackoverflow\Cronshedule\Model\

```
<?php
class Stackoverflow_Cronshedule_Model_Cron{ 
    public function lastModifiedProduct(){
         // update last modified product
    } 
}
```

At last, Set cron task for every minute in your cPanel for your /cron.php file.